# How does my computer split work between my 2 video cards?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dual-gpu

I have 2 video cards installed

1) (pcie x16) NVIDIA GTX 1060 6GB --> DVI Monitor A

2) (pcie x4) RADEON HD 7730 1GB --> HDMI Monitor B

B350

Ryzen7 1700 @ 3.7Ghz/1.224v

16GB DDR4 2800/1.212v

Running Windows 10 Pro, 2 monitors are on "Extend desktop"

The idea is I do my 3D stuff on the GTX1060's monitor, so that I can do other stuff like watch Youtube on my HD7730 monitor.

Say I do some V-Ray RT 3D rendering (or play a game, but I only play Diablo3 which even the single HD7730 can handle fine) on the GTX1060's monitor only. Is my HD7730 "weighing it down?"

Comment: "Is my HD7730 "weighing it down?" - No;  Unless you are using an application that uses DX12/Vulcan multi-gpu capabilities, then the application, is only using one of your GPUs.  SLI/Crossfire is a way to use multiple of the same card, which is different from, the muli-gpu capabilities.

Comment: I tried running Diablo3 in windowed mode. It looked like it performed EQUALLY on both monitors, and running GPU-Z, BOTH card sensors have around 30-35% gpu load, the GTX1060 loaded with 1250MB vram, while only 28MB vram on the HD7730. I also tried running Cinebench R15 OpenGL on both screens; it scored 98 on the GTX1060 screen, and 66 on the HD7730 screen. Could Windows just be using the primary adapter, and just doing a "pass through" the secondary card's monitor socket?

Comment: depends on the application but with "V-Ray RT 3D" it seems like it uses whatever it can find even if you have multiple gpu. But this link will tell you what you can do to control what your app uses. Theres a tool that allows you to choose your gpu and cpu:

https://docs.chaosgroup.com/display/VRAY3MAX/Set+Up+V-Ray+RT+GPU